# Setting Background Image of UITableView - White band appearing at bottom

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

When I use the following code to set the background of my UITableView to an image, about 20-30px of the image does not draw at the very bottom of the screen. I'm very puzzled by this as the image size is 480 high while the view is 460 high. The image should actually be sizing down to just barely fit the screen. Could somebody enlighten me? Thanks a lot

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]];
self.tableView.backgroundView = imageView;
```

[image]

Comment: Did you check your `UIImageView`'s auto-resizing mask?

Comment: I tried doing that but it doesn't show up because the strip is completely white at the bottom so it blends in with the stackoverflow webpage. It's just a 20 px or so white strip. I think it might have to do with the auto-resizing but I don't know how to prevent that...

Comment: @Legolas You can actually sort of see where the white band starts and stops...

Comment: The problem might also be the frame of your table view...check that, and it's parent if necessary.  It just looks like the whole thing is not properly positioned under the status bar, but the status bar is overlapping whatever view is containing everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the frame of the background image to this:

`{{0, -20}, {320, 480}}` either in IB or in code.

ie

```
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -20, 320, 480);
```

Comment: oh i misread that you are using a table.. it is most likely the frame of the tableview that is a problem. are you adding/position the tableview in code or in IB? what is the value of its frame property? If the frame of the table is messed up (it isn't reaching the bottom), nothing you do to its background image could help since it is still constrained by the frame of the table.

Comment: I found the issue, and it was related to how I was creating the tableviewcontroller and adding it to the appDelegate. I was setting the frames but I was not holding onto the controller itself, and that was causing several problems, including this one. All is fixed now though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the high  of of all the screen is 480 px and the statusBar has 20 px so your view has 460 px